# Javascript :: Why Object.hasOwnProperty('caller') returns true?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Object inherits from Function.prototype which in turn inherits from Object.prototype.

this is because internally, Object is actually a function

```
function Object(){[native code]}
```

which is why we can write code like

```
var ob=new Object();
```

Object inherits properties like 'caller' , 'arity' ,etc from Function.prototype

However (and this is what's confusing)

```
alert(Object.hasOwnProperty('caller')); //returns TRUE ! surprising
```

shouldn't it return false since Object actually inherits 'caller' property from Function.prototype ?

Same way

```
alert(Function.hasOwnProperty('caller')); 
/*returns True. expected 'false' as Function object has no property of its own and inherits everything from Function.prototype*/

alert(Number.hasOwnProperty('caller')); //again returns true, unexpectedly
```

So, someone has any idea about why this is happening ?

thank you very much. I hope I am not sounding naive

**EDIT**

trying `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object)` indeed returned `'caller'` as a property directly on Object itself.
So `Object.hasOwnProperty('caller')` is factually correct

But , now the question is why in MDN documentation, `'caller'` is mentioned as inherited from Function. 
So it definitely leading to confusion .

So is this some mistake in the documentation ?
thank you.

**EDIT-2**

Can I reach the conclusion that Object has its own

`caller`, `length`, etc properties 
as even
`Object.length` and `Object.__proto__.length` is not the same . It should have been equal if indeed Object was inheriting length property from its `[[prototype]]` , i.e `Function.prototype`
but its not the case

The thing is why does MDN mention that Object just inherits `caller`, `length`, `arity` , etc from its `[[prototype]]` object ? its a bit misleading IMHO

Comment: In which browser / JS engine does `Object.hasOwnProperty('caller')` yield `true`? I cannot reproduce in Opera.

Comment: @Bergi in current Firefox for example

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function):

> A function created with a function declaration is a Function object
>   and has all the properties, methods and behavior of Function objects.

In strict mode every function has an own `caller` and `arguments` property. See ES5 Spec [15.3.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5) and [13.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2).

> Function instances that correspond to strict mode functions (13.2) and
>   function instances created using the Function.prototype.bind method
>   (15.3.4.5) have properties named “caller” and “arguments” that throw a
>   TypeError exception.

Comment: Uh, `Object` is probably not a function created with a function declaration?

Comment: but I am not using strict mode as
I am not using `use strict;`
Secondly, so what even if its a Function object ?
the thing is even the `Function` object itself doesn't have any **own property** . All of it inherits from Function.prototype.
So even if Object was a Function, it still shouldn't have showed 
`Object.hasOwnProperty('caller');` as true

Comment: @Sarabjeet You can't control the creation of `Object`. Obviously they're created in strict mode. Please read [13.2 Step 19](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2). The `caller` and `arguments` properties will be added on creation, not inherited.